# Changing an object after pushing its address to a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a question:

```
class B : public class A {
public:
  vector<int*> vec; 
};

class A  {
};

vector<A*> vec_a;
vector<B*> vec_b;
```

if I push back an object of class `B` into both vectors.

```
B* b = new B;
vec_a.push_back(b);
vec_b.push_back(b);
```

then after that, I change something inside the object of class `B`,

such as:

```
int* i = ....
vec_b[0].push_back(i);
```

Does the `vec_a` change?

I am confused with that since I have checked that when vector push_back, it will only create a copy. But when I checked with the above codes, it changes. Are the two vectors hold a shared memory of object `b`?

Thanks

Comment: `vec_a` doesn't change, `vec` inside B object does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vectors contain pointers to a common object. Therefore anything you change inside that object via a derefence of one of those pointers is reflected in the object that they are pointing to. Adding the pointers to the vectors creates a copy of the pointers themselves, not the object they point to. Had you added a common **instance** of class `B` to both vectors, each vector would contain a separate copy of that object. Adding pointers results copies of your original pointer being added to each vector - but both copies will have the same value and that is the memory address of the object they point to.

Comment: I agreed with you , you make me clear now. But It seems that the above guys have different options.

Comment: @forester2012 Maybe you have misunderstood my answer. All the answers here say the same thing, just in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when pushing to a `vector` a copy is created. However in your case it's a copy of a *pointer*, not a copy of the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting a pointer to the same object in both vectors so any change to the object, pointed from an element in `vec_a` will affect the element in `vec_b`, too.

Comment: I agree with you , and test show that it was right. Now I am more clear now with these theories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You create only one object, after all. You push pointers. So `std::vector` copy pointers, but you change memory they point to.
That's why you get your results. I suggest you read a bit more about pointers.

Comment: yeah, I will read pointers more. Actually I want vec_b because in that I can easily refer to my things using [] but vec_a has a lot of other kinds of objects. Thats why my problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

The vector push_back method indeed does create a copy. But since you have specified vector of pointers (to vec_a and vec_b), copying those pointer does not actually change the original object. You would get what you originally expected if you used

```
vector<A> vec_a;
vector<B> vec_b;
```

instead, filling those vectors with

```
B b;
vec_a.push_back(b);
vec_b.push_back(b);
```

would actually copy the content of b into the vectors. Changing one will not affect the other.